# Reset an INotifyPropertyChanged from within an IRaiseItemChangedEvents

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, reset

I am doing something wrong with the plumbing here.

I have a structure than implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
Private Function ShouldPersistEndTime() As Boolean
    Return ShouldPersist()
End Function
Private Sub ResetEndTime()
    Reset()
End Sub
Public Property EndTime As Date Implements iTimePeriod.StartTime
    Get
        ...
    End Get
    Set(value As Date)
         ...
         NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
```

When I use this on its own (changing it to a class for the test) I can check that the property can be reset and reset it.

When I use it in an IRaiseItemChangedEvents it breezes past both the check and the reset without triggering the procedures in the INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
Case ListChangedType.ItemChanged
    If e.PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(sender(e.NewIndex)) Then
        e.PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(sender(e.NewIndex))
    End If
```

The status of the variables are:

```
e.PropertyDescriptor.Name = "EndTime"
e.NewIndex = 0
sender = the iRaiseItemChangedEvents class instance
sender(e.NewIndex) = the iNotifyPropertyBindicng structure instance
```

If I put a break point in the Sub ResetEndTime() it doesn't get hit.

I think I may be passing the wrong argument but I really have no idea. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "When I use it in an IRaiseItemChangedEvents it breezes past both the check and the reset without triggering the procedures in the INotifyPropertyChanged." What do you mean. The BindingList should not affect whither the `INPC` `PropertyChanged` event gets raised. Or are you listening on the `BindingList.ListChanged` event. If so, then you might want to try setting `BindlingList.RaiseListChangedEvent = true`.

Comment: Thanks @Aron. Yes I am listing to the ListChanged event and it is firing - what is not happening is the e.PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(sender(e.NewIndex)) is not calling ResetStartTime() in sender(e.NewIndex).

Comment: Unless you have a `DefaultValueAttribute` or have a `ShouldPersistMyProperty` method or a `ResetMyProperty`. `e.PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue()` will always return false. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.canresetvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Aron I do have a ShouldPersistStartTime - I included it in the code snippet.

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: @Aron In the circumstances it should return true *but* when I put a break inside it, it is not firing.